# WordPress CLI not finding core files

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-cli

trying to use the WP CLI for search-replace but it is not working, I get this message below.

```
Error: This does not seem to be a WordPress installation.
Pass --path=`path/to/wordpress` or run `wp core download`
```

I am running this command at the root of the WP site

thoughts?

Comment: Do any of the other WP CLI commands work, or it's limited to `search-replace`?

Comment: @Caleb do only one that works is the `wp --info`

Comment: What's the WP CLI version? `wp cli version`

Comment: @Caleb I am running 2.8

Comment: Hmm, the error message should be different if you're on 2.8.

Comment: @Caleb, yea WP-CLI version: 2.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of WP CLI specifically looks for `wp-includes/version.php` in the `ABSPATH` directory: check that `ABSPATH` constant is properly defined, and that `wp-includes/version.php` file exists inside of directory defined in `ABSPATH` constant.

Source: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/main/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php#L960

Comment: I dont seem to have a ABSPATH directory.

Comment: Sorry, I took a bit of liberty in my answer: I've updated to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be in your wordpress directory where your core files are to run that command